# laravel ErrorException can not create controller

Tags: laravel

```
[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\app/Http/Controllers/MyblogsController.php): 
   failed to open stream: No such file or directory.
```

when it ask for create controller this error is shown.i have composer installed and updated

Comment: Did you try running `composer install` or `composer update`?

Comment: tahnks to all answers its working now

Comment: ok but how to accept

Answer (score 0):

Try running `composer install` on your project directory.

Also make sure you give write permission to the `app/storage` directory.
From [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#configuration)

> Laravel may require one set of permissions to be configured: folders within app/storage require write access by the web server.